# Tee-Object to two pipelines?

Tags: powershell

I have the following code.

```
$summary = . {
    while ($true) { 
        # Generating huge list of psobject 
    }
} | 
Tee-Object -FilePath 'fname.csv' | # Need to process the input objects before writing to CSV
    Group-Object -Property xxx | Select Name,Count
```

However, I need to process the input objects before writing to fname.csv. Is it possible to Tee the object to two pipelines?

I tried

```
$summary = . {
    while ($true) { 
        # Generating huge list of psobject 
    }
} | 
For-Each {
    $_ | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Out-File -Append 'file.csv'
    $_
} |
Group-Object -Property xxx | Select Name,Count
```

But the headers are repeated every line in file.csv.

Comment: Insert the processing instructions *before* the `Tee-Object`?

Comment: Just fyi out-file encodes in unicode by default.  Excel likes ascii a little better.  You could use export-csv -append instead of both convertto-csv and out-file -append.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you want to do.  Does this help?  The objects from get-process get passed to two different pipelines.

```
get-process cmd | foreach-object { $_ | measure-object
                                   $_ | export-csv -append whatever.csv }
```

Comment: That is indeed the only solution, given that it's not possible to "tee" to _commands_ (pipelines). `Measure-Object` is an unfortunate example command to use, however, given that it is being applied to a single object. Not adapting the example to the specifics of the question led the OP to post their own answer.

Comment: @mklement0 Too bad ps doesn't have process substitution like zsh `paste <(cut -f1 FILE1) <(cut -f3 FILE2) | tee >(PROCESS1) >(PROCESS2) >/dev/null`

Comment: Agreed - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4284

Answer (score 1):

This should do the work in the question. It doesn't Tee to two pipelines, which may be needed for some use cases, though.

```
$summary = . {
    while ($true) { 
        # Generating huge list of psobject 
    }
} | 
ForEach {
    $_ | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Append 'file.csv'
    $_
} |
Group-Object -Property xxx | Select Name,Count
```

Comment: It's good to frame the answer in terms of your question, but in essence it is identical to [js2010's  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58490324/45375).

Comment: I didn't try the answer - the measure is in the foreach block in the answer. Will it generate one measure for every item?

Comment: Yes, it will, but I think the particular command used was just an (ill-chosen) example to demonstrate the technique of sending the pipeline input object at hand (`$_`) to two other pipelines - which is the only way to get what you want, given that it's not possible to "tee" directly to (multiple) other commands (pipelines).

Answer (score 0):

Going after @mklement0 's guidance, does the below make it any simpler,

```
Get-Process excel | Tee-Object -Variable process | group processname | select name, count
$process | Export-Csv "D:\Op_GetProcessExcel.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

---

**Previous suggestion**

As @AnsgarWiechers pointed out something like the following should work for you,

```
Get-Process | 
    group processname | 
    select name, count | 
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | 
    Tee-Object "C:\Op_GetProcess.csv"
```

Comment: The OP suggests that exporting should happen _before_ applying `Group-Object` and `Select-Object`, so this won't help.